# Flask - format site url to display search query

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to display the search from a form in the url like `https://website.com/search?q=query`. How can I do that in flask?

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search = StringField('search', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm()
    query = form.data['search']
    if query != '':
        items = Foo.query.filter(Foo.name.like('%'+query+'%')).all()
        table = ItemTable(items)
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, query=query, table=table)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

templates/index.html

```
{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
  <form style="display: inline;" action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post" name="search">
    {{ form.search(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

  {% if table %}
    <h1>Search results for "{{ query }}":</h1>
    {{ table }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock page_content %}
```

Comment: Please post your form so we can answer properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `https://website.com/search?q=query`, the url namespace is `search` and `q` is a GET request argument. In order to make this work in Flask, you need to route your view at `/search` and retrieve `q` from GET request args. WTForms allows your form to use GET or POST method depending on your instantiation. This is described in Flask's docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/wtforms/).

Finally, your code can look something like this:

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    q = StringField('q', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm(request.args)
    query = request.args.get('q', None)
    table = None
    if query is not None:
        items = Foo.query.filter(Foo.name.like('%'+query+'%')).all()
        table = ItemTable(items)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, query=query, table=table)
```

templates/index.html:

```
{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
  <form style="display: inline;" action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="get" name="search">
    {{ form.q(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

  {% if table %}
    <h1>Search results for "{{ query }}":</h1>
    {{ table }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock page_content %}
```

I also refactored your code a little bit, because calling render_template twice for almost similar logic seems quite redundant.

Comment: I'm getting an `405 method not allowed` error. Could you include the html?

Comment: You just need to change method of your form in html from 'post' to 'get'

Comment: I get the error after changing that and the `form.search` to `form.q`

Comment: I have added html to my answer. Are you getting the same 405 error after changing form method in **html**?